# Get the JPA filed name when we extended the metadata in olingo

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, olingo

[Here](https://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata2/tutorials/jparedefinemetadata.html) it has been explained how can we extend `metadata` of an oData service in olingo V2.

```xml
<JPAEntityType name="SalesOrderHeader">
   <EDMEntityType>SalesOrder</EDMEntityType> 
   <EDMEntitySet>SalesOrders</EDMEntitySet> 
   <JPAAttributes>
       <JPAAttribute name="soId">ID</JPAAttribute> 
       <JPAAttribute name="netAmount">NetAmount</JPAAttribute> 
       <JPAAttribute name="buyerAddress">BuyerAddressInfo</JPAAttribute> 
   </JPAAttributes>
   <JPARelationships>
       <JPARelationship name="salesOrderItem">SalesOrderLineItemDetails</JPARelationship> 
       <JPARelationship name="notes">NotesDetails</JPARelationship> 
    </JPARelationships>
</JPAEntityType>
```

This small snippet of code explained how I can change a `JPA` entity field's name `buyerAddress` to the new name `BuyerAddressInfo`.

**Now the question is how can I access to the original name when I have access to `BuyerAddressInfo` and `ODataJPAContext`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered following method from [here](https://olingo.apache.org/javadoc/odata2/org/apache/olingo/odata2/jpa/processor/api/access/JPAEdmMappingModelAccess.html). By this method I can access `BuyerAddressInfo` by having `buyerAddress` and JPA Entity name!

```java
import org.apache.olingo.odata2.jpa.processor.api.access.JPAEdmMappingModelAccess;
import org.apache.olingo.odata2.jpa.processor.api.factory.ODataJPAFactory;
// .....
JPAEdmMappingModelAccess jpaEdmMappingModelAccess = 
ODataJPAFactory.createFactory().getJPAAccessFactory().getJPAEdmMappingModelAccess(oDataJPAContext);
jpaEdmMappingModelAccess.loadMappingModel();
String newName = jpaEdmMappingModelAccess.mapJPAAttribute("SalesOrderHeader", "SalesOrderHeader"));
```

However what I am looking for is exactly vice versa! Therefore at the moment I use a Map and collect all the pairs and each time I iterate over them!